# How to synchronously refresh a access token with project reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm accessing a external rest api which is secured using OpenID connect. I must run a job which calls the api several times before it completes. This job may be executed in parallel using several concurrent threads. Thus I use a service for api access which is instantiated for each job:

```java
private AccessAndRefresTokens tokens; // I initially get that from somewhere else

public Mono<Result> callTheApi(){
  return createWebClientWith(tokens.accessToken).executeRequest();
}

public Mono<Result> callOtherApiFunction(){
  return createWebClientWith(tokens.accessToken).executeRequest();
}

public Mono<Result> callYetAnotherApiFunction(){
  return createWebClientWith(tokens.accessToken).executeRequest();
}
```

As my job is executed it might happen that the access token expires between two api calls. To prevent this from happening, I like to check the validity of the access token before every request and refresh it if necessary.

My first idea was to do the validity check inside a flatMap operator:

```java
Mono.just(tokens).flatMap(tokens -> {
  if(accessTokenExpired){
    return refreshAccessToken().doOnNext(refreshedTokens -> tokens = refreshedTokens);
  }else{
    return Mono.just(tokens.accessToken);
  }
}).flatMap(accessToken -> createWebClientWith(accessToken));
```

However it seems to me that this would trigger the refresh several times if multiple threads access the service and the refresh has not yet completed. As a consequence I would end up refreshing the access token several times in a very short time which might fail due to rate limits.

I am new to the whole reactive thing and I suppose using a `synchronized` block is not a desired option. So I tried to figure out something using reactor's `Processor` but I could not find a satisfying solution.

So is there a way to ensure the access token is refershed only once? And how do I achieve this without using blocking code?

Comment: I know this question is old, but I'm curious how you ended up solving it since I'm in a similar boat.

Comment: The possible solution depends on the spring boot version you are using. The processor I ended up using was deprecated in one of the last releases. However I will try to find some time and write up an answer to this

Comment: Rechecking the code I noticed, that I never got arround  `synchronized` blocks moreover, recent project reactor versions did deprecate the ReplayProcessor that we used. Thus, we already did a rewrite in the affected project which does not use any project reactor parts. Sorry I cannot help you further